# Switch from Rhel7 to Rhel9 | system-auth vs SSSD

Tags: sssd

Now that I've decided to switch from RHEL7 to RHEL9, I've previously configured my Rhel7 `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` etc, but if my understanding is correct it's preferred to used `authselect` together with `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` for RHEL9, please correct me if this is incorrectly.

Or is it still possible fo